# Docker swarm, ruby gems not install: bundle install error , not fetching

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-swarm, redmine

I have a problem with my redmine installation in docker swarm

When I try to install any redmine plugin in a docker swarm installations:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
```

Al the trace since container init:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem puma (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
Install missing gems with bundle install.
Your Gemfile lists the gem puma (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error
<SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (getaddrinfo:
Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
```

Any clues about how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like https connections are not enabled. Can you verify wether they are or not?

Comment: you have reason, was a docker problem about egress traffic, thank you